# AWS cron expression to run a job every 2 days once

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a requirement to schedule a job in AWS CloudWatch events to be run once in every two days. I am using the below expression but getting a error Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid

```
cron(0 0 */2 * ? *)
```

The below is the java code,

```
String cronExpression = "cron(0 0 */2 * ? *)"
    PutRuleRequest request = new PutRuleRequest();
        request
            .withName(eventName)
            .withRoleArn("arn:aws:iam::****")
            .withScheduleExpression(cronExpression)
            .withState(RuleState.ENABLED);
        PutRuleResult result = cloudwatchConfig.cloudwatch().putRule(request);
```

Comment: Where are you creating this rule.. terraform?

Comment: Creating it in java code with aws-java-sdk library.

Comment: Show us the code then

Comment: have updated the question with code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cron(0 0 1/2 * ? *)
```

You can verify [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html).

Comment: Getting same error - Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.

Comment: `0 0 1/2 * ? *`, for some reason aws works in a different way... I edited the answer.

Comment: This works fine. I am able to schedule jobs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your syntax into cloudwatch, it too will report the same error you are seeing in the terraform,but fix it simple

```
cron(0 0 1-31/2 * ? *)
```

The explanation for each field is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

1-31 covers all the possible number of days in a month